# Desire2Learn updating a username

Tags: desire2learn

Does the Desire2Learn Valence API allow you to modify a person's Username via the [PUT /.../users/(userId)](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#put--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-users-%28D2LID-userId%29) call?

We have a use case where a user does a legal name change, and their Username (format = Firstname.Lastname) has to be updated in D2L.

I understand that the SIS-to-D2L integration uses Username as one of two integration keys (the other is OrgDefinedId), so modifying a person's Username that way would fail.

So then, what are the key(s) for the PUT /users/(userid) Valence call, and will D2L allow you to modify a Username this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a User, the user's `UniqueIdentifier` property gets set to the `UserName` property you pass within the `CreateUserData` structure. The `UniqueIdentifier property` is *not* modifiable after that point through the API; however, the `UserName` property is -- you can update the `UserName` in the D2L LMS user record. As far as the LMS is concerned, the `UserId` property is the only part of the user record that *it* depends upon being unique.

When you change the `UserName` property, the service has an underlying task that notices the change and propagates the change to the `UniqueIdentfier` property. Currently, because this propagation happens separately from the update, the update action taken through the API (which returns an updated user structure) *may not* show the `UniqueIdentifier` in sync with the `UserName`. A subsequent fetch of that user's data (by Id, otherwise) should have the two properties back in sync again.

Comment: Ok, from your answer I understand that the PUT /users/(userid) call is keyed on the D2L UserId, and it CAN be used to modify the UserName. The internal D2L UserId is the only value that can't be changed. FYI, I've tested the UniqueIdentifier field as part of the SIS integration, and it appears that CAN be re-mapped via the SIS integration. My understanding is that this happens if D2L receives a SIS data object that matches on  OrgDefinedId and UserName.

Comment: I think you are correct -- also the system has a separate worker task that keeps the UniqueIdentifier in sync with the UserName, but latency might cause the User record returned on an API PUT to show the data out of sync. Re-fetching the user record should show the data back in sync again. I revised the answer accordingly.